# Overloading validate in cerberus

Tags: python, python-3.x, cerberus

I'd like to overload validate in my custom validator class so that if the client only gives me text, I can convert it to yaml for validation.

I've tried the following:

```
import cerberus
from cerberus import Validator
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

class SchemaValidator(Validator):
    def _validate(self, schema_to_check_in_text, schema_from_catalog_in_yaml):
        ruamel_yaml = YAML()
        parsed_proposed_yaml = ruamel_yaml.load(schema_to_check_in_text)

        self.validate(parsed_proposed_yaml, schema_from_catalog_in_yaml)
```

But it doesn't work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not overloading anything, but adding an extra method that you marks as private per convention.